# Spring security + Struts 1.2 integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, ldap, struts

I have a application in which I used struts1.2 and ejb2.1 now I want to add spring security using LDAP server in it.
How to integrate [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/articles.html) with struts1.2?

Comment: http://spring3mvc.wordpress.com/2012/06/25/spring-security-with-struts-1-3/ I got good tutorial regarding your question

Answer (score 1):

Integration shouldn't be different than any other web app.

1. You need the spring-security dependencies either the jars or the maven dependencies. I'll post the maven dependencies, if you don't use maven you can look the jars up from here: [mvn browser](http://www.mvnbrowser.com/artifact-details.html?groupId=org.jsefa&artifactId=jsefa&version=0.9.2&tab=REPOSITORIES#tabs)

   ```
   <properties>
     <spring.version>3.0.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
   </properties>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
     <version>${spring.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
     <version>${spring.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
     <version>${spring.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
     <version>${spring.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. You need the `FilterChainProxy` defined in your `web.xml`:

   ```
   <filter>
     <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
     <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
   ```
3. You need your spring context locations defined in your `web.xml`:

   ```
   <context-param>
     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>WEB-INF/spring-contexts/myContextConfig.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>
   ```
4. You need the ContextLoaderListener defined in your `web.xml`:

   ```
   <listener>
     <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
   ```
5. Finally for a basic security config you can have a look at the [petclinic tutotial app](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/petclinic-tutorial.html).

That should do it.

Comment: Unfortunately that tutorial is no longer available. Do you have another?

Comment: @dah you can find a version of it on archive.org --> https://web.archive.org/web/20110823024934/http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/petclinic-tutorial.html