# How to implement Spring security in Struts 1 (not in struts 2)

Tags: jsp, spring-security, struts, dao

I am developing Enterprise level web application where security should be top notched. So, can someone please suggest me how to implement security of spring in struts 1 application.

I am new to Spring but I know Struts well.If some proper documentation is available please provide link for same.

Any other suggestions are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can see many implementations, if you googled well.

See the below links,

> - [spring-security-with-struts-1-3](https://spring3mvc.wordpress.com/2012/06/25/spring-security-with-struts-1-3/)
> - [spring-securitys-integration-with-struts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500805/spring-securitys-integration-with-struts?)
> - [spring-security-struts-1-2-intregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471613/spring-security-struts-1-2-intregation)

For basic **spring security**,

- [Spring Security - Tutorial: Adding Security to Spring Petclinic](https://web.archive.org/web/20110823024934/http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/petclinic-tutorial.html)

Using **Servlet filters**,

- [How to secure a Struts 1.3 application](http://classfoundexception.blogspot.in/2012/04/how-to-secure-struts-13-application.html)